# Filtering JS with an 'OR' and not an 'AND'

Tags: javascript, jquery, filtering

I'm having a problem with my jQuery filters overriding each other. For example if I wanted to see mens and womens, the mens matches items #1 and sets it to show but then sets it to hide since womens is not in the data attribute with a `$.inArray(filter.value, item.data("attributes")) == -1`. Is there a way to compare 2 arrays (one being the filters selected and the other being item.data("attributes")) and show distinct items that have one or more matches. (i.e. I want mens and womens fashion in blue or red color)

```
$('.filter').on('click', function() {
        filters = $('.filter:checked');
        if (filters.length == 0)
            $('.list-o-glasses').show();
        else {
            $('.list-o-glasses').hide();
            $('.list-o-glasses').each(function(index, val) {
                var item = $(this);
                var show = true;
                $(filters).each(function(i, filter) {
                    if ($.inArray(filter.value, item.data("attributes")) == -1) {
                        show = false;
                    }
                });

                if (show)
                    $('#' + $(item).attr("id")).show();
                else
                    $('#' + $(item).attr("id")).hide();
            });
        }
    });\
```

Here is the rendered HTML:

```
<div class="row shop-grid grid-view">
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 list-o-glasses" id="BSG034BN" data-attributes="[&quot;men&quot;,&quot;wayfarer&quot;,&quot;metal&quot;,&quot;145&quot;,&quot;135&quot;,&quot;brown&quot;,&quot;brown&quot;]" style="display: block;">
</div>
</div>
```

Thanks and let me know if you have any ideas!

Comment: can't see your HTML, but would it work if you just remove the else hide statement? `else $('#' + $(item).attr("id")).hide();`

Comment: Your `$(filters).each(` looks wrong... You already have `filters` defined as jQuery object, so why are you passing it to $() again?

Comment: @jas7457 - You're right and I removed the $() surrounding the filter variable

Comment: @andi - Remove the else and it still hides. the rest of the items. I added the html element that the JS works with.

Comment: You have a logic error in your procedure.  You turn them all on, then you iterate them, and then check each filter for a match...  First filter you get a match, show remains true, but next filter, no match, you set show back false.  Remove else on the if(show), if you get a match on a filter, break the loop, you don't need to check any more filters, then iterate to next item

Comment: Change `$('#' + $(item).attr("id"))` to `item`, which is already a jQuery object pointing to an element with the ID you're looking up. Your example HTML doesn't include anything with a class of `filter`. We're looking for a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

```
var show = false;
$(filters).each(function(i, filter) {
  if ($.inArray(filter.value, item.data("attributes")) <> -1) {
    show = true;
    return false;  //matched a filter, break the loop
  }
});

if (show)
  $('#' + $(item).attr("id")).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Without your HTML to test on, I'm putting this out here as a guess. What I've done here is flip the logic.

First, it shows all of the rows. Then it goes through each row, getting the applicable attributes. For each of these attributes, it searches for a matching checked filter. If at least one matches, it keeps the row visible. Otherwise, it hides it. You can find out more about [`some` at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some), and [`toggle`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/#toggle-display) and [`is`](http://api.jquery.com/is/) at jQuery's site.

```js
$(function() {
  $('.filter').on('click', function() {
    var filters = $('.filter:checked');
    $('.list-of-glasses').show();
    $('.list-of-glasses').each(function() {
      var item = $(this);
      var attrs = item.data("attributes");
      var show = attrs.some(function(attr) {
        return filters.is('input[value="' + attr + '"]');
      });
      item.toggle(show);
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
<li><label>Men's<input type="checkbox" checked value="mens" class="filter"></label></li>
<li><label>Women's<input type="checkbox" checked value="womens" class="filter"></label></li>
<div class="list-of-glasses" data-attributes="[&quot;mens&quot;]">Men's</div>
<div class="list-of-glasses" data-attributes="[&quot;mens&quot;,&quot;womens&quot;]">Unisex</div>
<div class="list-of-glasses" data-attributes="[&quot;womens&quot;]">Women's</div>
```